# Android app says the file does not exist but it does. I need to install it

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Here is my code:

```
        String dir = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
        File myFile = new File(dir+"/file.apk");

        if (myFile.exists())
        {
            textView.setText("File exists.");
        }
        else
        {
            textView.setText("File does not exist.");
        }
```

myFile.exists() is false. I do not know why. The file exists and it is located in the directory.

When I solve the problem, I'll try this:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
            intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(myFile));
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE, true);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Can somebody help? Why it does not see the file?

UPDATE:

It's really strange. If I use code:

```
            if (myFile.exists())
            {
                textView.setText("it exists");
            }
            else
            {
                textView.setText(myFile.getAbsolutePath());
            }
```

, it goes to 'else' and shows the path to the file which 'does not exist'.

Comment: app never say false! check file exist or not using file explorer or check you are use correct file path or not?

Comment: It does exist. I can reach it via explorer and install manually.

Comment: verify file path once again!

Comment: Add exact address in explorer and from code. Also have u given permission to read from SD CARD?

Comment: Yes, I Have added: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Are you on android 6.0?

Comment: path from code and from explore.. are same?

Comment: Yes, they are the same. I checked it carefully. dir string is proper.

Comment: Is there any other way I can force app to find the file?

Comment: Can you post the value of myFile.getAbsolutePath() by debugging? It's possible you are adding an unwanted file separator

Comment: Sure. It's:    /data/data/com.mycompany.updater/files

Comment: It's really strange. If I use code: if (myFile.exists())
            {
                textView.setText("it exists");
            }
            else
            {
                textView.setText(myFile.getAbsolutePath());

            }, it returns the path.

Comment: myFile.getAbsolutePath() is returning the path because file variable was initialized with that path and file name. Can you pl add the file path value according to your code.

Comment: It's: /data/data/com.mycompany.updater/files/file.apk

Comment: is your targetSdk 23 ?

Comment: Yes, android:targetSdkVersion="23".

Comment: 'It does exist. I can reach it via explorer and install manually'. But not in getFilesDir() as that is private memory for your app only. A file explorer cannot reach that path. So you are using other paths with your file explorer.

Comment: The path getFilesDir() returns is the same which explorer suggests. I pasted the path.

Comment: Sorry but i do not understand a word of this. Which path do you see in the file explorer? As said already two times before: a file explorer cannot see that path of getFilesDir(). Which file explorer app do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to greenapps:

"Please click in Astro app left to the word Primary on the up arrow to see the real path. /Primary/ does not exist on an Android device. It's an Astro invention. And Astro shows external memory with Primary. And take a better file explorer like ES File Explorer to inform you about real paths"

I used direct path I found using Astro (modified string dir to '/sdcard/data/data/...").

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
    String dir = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
    boolean fileExists = (new File(dir + "/file.apk")).isFile();

    if (fileExists)
    {
        // your file exists
    }
    else
    {
        // your file does not exist
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you construct the file with the 2-arg constructor, you can avoid adding a system-dependent path separator character. Like this:

```
    File myFile = new File(dir, "file.apk");
```